# How to choose where to print to?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that prints the name of all worksheets in the workbook:

```
Sub GetSheetNames()

Dim i%
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets(i).Name
Next i

End Sub
```

Whenever I run the macro, it prints the name in whatever cell I have selected. I want it to print it in its own separate sheet. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to qualify where you want the output.  An unqualified reference defaults to your current sheet.  For instance this will output to Sheet2 starting a row 1 and column 1:

```
Sub GetSheetNames()

Dim i%
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
 Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets(i).Name
Next i

End Sub
```

See how the Cells(i,1).Value now has a sheet reference in front?  Depending on where you want to start, you may have to add a row counter.  Having the loop iterator for both the sheet name reference AND the cell reference may not be what you ultimately want.

An example of having the sheets starting at another row (in this example, row 10) would look something like this:

```
Sub GetSheetNames()

Dim i%
Dim rowCounter As Long

rowCounter = 10
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
 Sheet2.Cells(rowCounter, 1).Value = Sheets(i).Name
 rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Another way to qualify a sheet name:

```
Sub GetSheetNames()

Dim i%
Dim rowCounter As Long

rowCounter = 10
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
 Sheets("YourSheetNameHere").Cells(rowCounter, 1).Value = Sheets(i).Name
 rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: how can i specify a sheet name for it to print to

Comment: @user2778618 I edited in another way to qualify a sheet name.  Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub GetSheetNames()


Dim i%
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
Sheets("Lists").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets(i).Name
Next i
Sheets("Lists").Activate 'if you want this sheet to be displayed after your macro is executed
End Sub
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: i don't want it to make a new sheet. i just want it to print to a specified sheet that is already created.

Comment: Ah, I see.  What is the name of the specified sheet? I'll try to adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: could you show me? im running into some compile errors

Comment: oh the sheet name is "Lists"

Comment: I edited my post to reference your specified sheet.  Try that and let me know.